# How to make a URL filter to route actions with Servlets?

Tags: jsp, url, servlets, routes

I'm currently developing a Java EE web framework and I would want to know how I could route my URL's... I want support HMVC feature! URL's will follow this rule:

/module_name/controller_name/action_name, where:

module_name: path separated by slashes... Ex.: Submodule "Y" of Module "X": /X/Y
controller_name: name of controller with no special chars
action_name: name of action with no special chars

I would like map /module_name/controller_name/ to a specific servlet controller! Action part is a public method on that class! :)

How I could do this? Using filters? I want an example, if possible!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

i see 3 ways: filter, basic servlet(all requests via main servlet) or "servlet-mapping"

**filter**

This example rewrite url

```
http://example.org/<int value>
```

to

```
http://example.org/user?id=<int value>
```

i.e

```
http://example.org/1234 -> http://example.org/user?id=1234
```

1. determinate filter in web.xml

> ```
> <filter>
>     <filter-name>Router</filter-name>
>     <filter-class>org.example.Router</filter-class>
>     <init-param>
>         <param-name>param1</param-name>
>         <param-value>valueOfparam1</param-value>
>     </init-param>
> </filter>
> <filter-mapping>
>     <filter-name>Router</filter-name>
>     <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> 
> </filter-mapping>
> ```

in init-param section you can specify route rules

1. filter class

   ```
   public class Router implements javax.servlet.Filter {

   private static final Pattern REWRITE_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("(^[1-9]\\d*)$");

   @Override
   public void destroy() {
   }

   @Override
   public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain fc) throws IOException, ServletException {
   //this method calling before controller(servlet), every request

       HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
       String url = request.getRequestURL().toString();
       String number = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("/")).replace("/", "");

       Matcher m = REWRITE_PATTERN.matcher(number);
       if(m.find()) {
           RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("user?id=" + m.group(1));
           dispatcher.forward(req, res);
       } else {
           fc.doFilter(req, res);
       }
   }

   @Override
   public void init(FilterConfig fc) throws ServletException {
       //here you may read params from web.xml
   }}
   ```

**basic sevlet**

```
public class BasicServlet extends HttpServlet {
   //route rules here, and rewrite
}
```

**servlet-mapping**

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>UserServlet</servlet-name>
    <uri-mapping>/user/*</uri-mapping>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>PostServlet</servlet-name>
    <uri-mapping>/post/*</uri-mapping>
</servlet-mapping>
```

- filter - more flexible and not require serious modify working code
- basic servlet - flexible, require change you code
- servlet mapping - simply, not flexible(for specific route rules)