# How can I easily transfer my serverside variables from the Java code to the client-side code?

Tags: javascript, java, servlets, web

I'm making a web application with a Java engine. How can I easily transfer my server-side data from the Java code to the client-side code (HTML, css, JavaScript,...). I know about servlets but I don't know how to properly work with them.

We have a fully functional Java engine, a GUI made in HTML and CSS, now we need to use the data in both ways.

Here is some code in my servlet constructor:

```
public GameServlet() {
    super();
    int numberOfPlayers = 4;
    int[] wins = {1,2,3,4};
    int[] losses = {1,2,3,4};
    String[] players = {"player1", "player2", "player3", "player4"};
    Game game = new Game(numberOfPlayers, players, wins, losses);
    System.out.println("test");
    System.out.println(players[3]);
    game.Start();
}
```

How can I access for example the players array in my JavaScript code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [AJAX](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/) to get data from the server from client side.

[JQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) has a lot of helper functions to assist.

eg:

```
$.get('url/to/server-side/data').success(function(response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

Have at [how to do routing in java servlets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11680192/how-to-make-a-url-filter-to-route-actions-with-servlets).

You need to do a request like above, and then *filter* the url `url/to/server-side/data` to a server side method which responds the data.

Comment: please update your question with the code :)

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to posting questions! :)

Comment: Its okay :) - please comment on my answer if theres anything i can to to improve it. / if you dont understand anything.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! I'm now trying to update the src attribute from cards on the playfield at the load event on the web application. I have a string array in my servlet with all the paths, now I need to route the array to my javascript to change the actual sources. Do you understand what I'm trying to do?

Comment: If you have been pointed in the right direction to move forward and you feel that this question is solved, please mark the answer as the answer to this question :) thanks

Comment: Do you have any idea how I can do that in jquery? Some example code?

Comment: You cannot get the Java array to JavaScript array, two different things. The interface or 'Agreement' is the routes themselves